# How to access a variable outside the function

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I want to access variable numOfPlayers outside the Function and assign its value to variable numberOfTotalPlayers in same class, but i am unable to access it there, How i can do it?
Please ignore my code formatting and extra code, i just tried to make it workable.

This is almost complete code...

```
package com.example.zccscores

import android.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.zccscores.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.EditText

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var playerName: String
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore
    private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
    private var TotalScores: Long = 0
**    private var numberofTotalPlayers: Int = noOfPlayers
**

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)


        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE)

        noOfPlayers()
        for (i in 0 until numberofTotalPlayers) {
            showCustomDialog()
        }

        binding.fourBTN.setOnClickListener {
            TotalScores += 4
        }

        binding.sixBTN.setOnClickListener {
            TotalScores += 6
        }
        binding.singleBTN.setOnClickListener {
            TotalScores += 1
        }

    }
    private fun noOfPlayers() {
        val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_with_edittext, null)
**        val numOfPlayers = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.dialogEditText)
**
        numOfPlayers.inputType = android.text.InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(dialogView)
            .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, _ ->
                // Handle OK button click and retrieve the text from the EditText
                numberofTotalPlayers = numOfPlayers.text.toString().toInt()

                dialog.dismiss() // Dismiss the dialog after handling button click
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
                // Handle Cancel button click if needed
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancel clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                dialog.dismiss() // Dismiss the dialog after handling button click
            }

        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
    }


    private fun showCustomDialog() {
        val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_with_edittext, null)
        val dialogEditText = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.dialogEditText)
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setView(dialogView)
            .setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, _ ->
                // Handle OK button click and retrieve the text from the EditText
                val diologeFetchedPlayerName = dialogEditText.text.toString()
                if (diologeFetchedPlayerName.isNotBlank()) {

                    val playerData = Scores(232, diologeFetchedPlayerName, 89)


                    db.collection("ZCC Scores").document(diologeFetchedPlayerName).set(playerData)
                        .addOnSuccessListener {
                            binding.firstPlayerScores.text = playerData.toString()
                            Toast.makeText(
                                this,
                                "Player data saved from diologue",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()

                        }.addOnFailureListener {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                        }


                    binding.firstPlayerTV.text =diologeFetchedPlayerName
                       
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Player name saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid player name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }
                dialog.dismiss() // Dismiss the dialog after handling button click
            }
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
                // Handle Cancel button click if needed
                Toast.makeText(this, "Cancel clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                dialog.dismiss() // Dismiss the dialog after handling button click
            }

        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
    }


}
```

I tried to access that variable outside the function in

````
val numberOfTotalPlayers:Int = noOfPlayers //Getting error here
}```
````

Comment: you don't. that's a local variable, that doesn't exist outside of the scope of that method. You can turn it into an instance variable instead

Answer (score 0):

Variables in java/kotlin are scored to the context where they are declared. If you declare a variable inside a method you can only reach it from that method. This has the benefit that two methods inside a class that declare one variable each can use the same name, and its still two different variables.

**To reach a variable from different methods inside a class**, you can define it on class level and then reference of using `this.noOfPlayers`. It is now shared between all methods operating on the same object of that class.

**If you want to share it between different objects**, you normally declare getters and setters for that variable. **EDIT:** Or for Kotlin, visibility modifiers (default public)

Comment: Last sentence is not true in Kotlin, because we have properties. You *might* declare custom getters or setters for a property, but only if you need the custom behavior.

Comment: Can you please give an example of that claas, how that class should look like

Comment: I think someone else already did.  I honestly think that this is such a fundamental part of all OOP languages that I would suggest anyone to read up on this theory from a book or tutorial rather than trying to figure out it by example on SO. It will bring you a lot of value in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access it--it is *scoped* to that function. It only exists while that function is being executed, and a different copy of it exists every time that function is executed. So, it doesn't make logical sense to "reach into" the function and extract the variable value. It could be different every time that function is called, or maybe that function will never be called.

Also, your `numberofTotalPlayers: Int` property is initialized at the time the class is constructed, which is before `onCreate()` is ever called. At this time, your EditText doesn't even exist yet.

Even if it did, if you initialized your property right after the EditText is created, there will be no text in it yet. A property's initializer is called only one time, when the class is constructed.

You need to rethink your design of this class and focus on execution order of the code. Right now, it looks like you are trying to immediately prompt the user for a number of players, and then you try to immediately create as many dialogs as there are players. You can't do it this way because the number entered by the user isn't available until after they have entered it and closed the dialog, which will happen long after `onCreate()` has completed. Also, opening 4 dialogs immediately on top of each other will be a big mess. I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but you may need to use the *state machine design pattern* to make this work (you can look it up).